# How to display IBM mainfrance charset in IntelliJ (EBCDIC?)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ebcdic, file-encodings, character-set

I'm using IntelliJ and when I open data files in the editor, I can use the "character set" selector at the bottom right of the window to reload the file and display it in the appropriate charset

For example, I can switch between `UTF-8`, `ISO-8859-1` and `windows-1251`.

This works fine for various files I get from UNIX, Windows and Mac.

But I am working with files that come from an IBM mainframe (is it EBCDIC?) and I cant seem to get the special characters to display correctly.

Does anyone know how to display this charset (is it EBCDIC, my colleagued tipped me it might be `Cp277`, I'm not sure) in IntelliJ?

Comment: EBCDIC is a family of Character-sets. cp037 is US-EBCDIC cp273 is Austrian German. See http://www-01.ibm.com/software/globalization/ccsid/ccsid_registered.html.

Comment: If a file is coming from a Mainframe, It may have fixed length record (no \n) or VB (length based variable length records).

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in the latest version of intellij.

Select file encoding: `IBM277` - this corresponds to EBCDIC encoding Cp277.